# Determine if DataColumn is date only

Tags: c#, database

I have a DataTable object and can access its Columns collection.
For each item of this collection I need to determine the type of the column and return it as one of the following string: 'string' 'number' 'boolean' 'date' 'datetime' 'timeofday'.

So I do something like the following:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
  string colType = DermineColumnType(column);
}

. . . . 

string DeterminColumnType(DataColumn column) {
  Type sysType = column.DataType
  if (sysType == typeof(Boolen)
      return "boolean";
  else if (sysType == typeof(Decimal) || sysType == typeof(Double) || sysType == typeof(Int32) ...)
      return "number";
  . . . . . . 
  else
      return "string";

}
```

The problem is with 'date', 'datetime' and 'timeofday' values - I can't find any information in DataColumn class which allows me to determine whether this column is defined in database table as just "date", "time" or "datetime". 
DataType property of DataColumn class always returns System.DateTime type for all these cases. 
Is there any way to get this information based only on DataColumn and/or DataTable objects, without executing additional SQL statements?

Comment: Show how you are getting the data. You likely need to call [`.GetSchemaTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx) but we need to see how you are getting this result set to be sure and show you how to get the schema.

Comment: It something like the following:

`DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
dbAdapter.Fill(dataSet);`

Comment: And: yes we know about a possibility to use GetSchemaTable() or Connection.GetSchema() to get information about each column. I just wonder if there is any way to get this info just from a DataColumn object without an additional SQL requests (which all those methods will make in result). 
It seems it's impossible, unfortunately. Which is quite strange I must say.

Comment: Why would it be strange? DataTable is not just a SQL construct so it does not need to represents every type of datatype from every data source. Also I don't know if your OleProvider supports it but you should try `command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly)` that will run the query with `FMTONLY ON` so it does not return any rows but does return the schema info so you can call `GetSchemaTable()` without the overhead cost of running the query twice. That or switch from a `OleDbDataAdapter` to a `OleDbDataReader` so you can query the schema as you pull it out.

Comment: Thank you.
I know how to get information about table schema separately - I just would like to avoid additional querying. 
As for "why strange". Because we already get this information while executing our query. It would be great to have something like "OriginalColumnType" property in DataColumn class which would hold an original type name for this column simply as a string. It would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the type of data column by following code

```
 foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
  var v = column.GetType()
Return v.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date and Time are not valid data types for a DataColumn. DateTime and TimeSpan are the only date/time related data types.

It seems you won't be able to tell just from the type whether it's a Date or Time, you will need to look at the data inside the DateTime object or from the database.

For more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Comment: Of course we know that there are no such types as Date or Time in .NET. 
But these types are supported by the most of databases - so it will be great to know the original database type of this column having just an instance of DataColumn.